# Magento 2 - Injecting a model into a class? How to?

Tags: model, dependency-injection, class

I have a class where I'd like to inject a model into it, to use the code already created in the model. How would I go about doing this in my class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Module}\Path\to\Folder;

use {Vendor}\{Module}\Model\{modelName} 


class Xyz
{

    protected $myModel;

    public function __construct(
        ..
        {ModelName} $myModel
        ...
        ) {
        ...
        $this->myModel = $myModel;
        ...

    }


    public function execute()
    {
        ....

        $this->myModel->WhatEverFunction();

        ....
    }
}
```

Hope above will help!